# create table from two input tables .output table's key will be from first input and values will be from second input table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am having a table in which I am passing names:

`names = {'Sachin', 'Ponting', 'Dhoni'}`

and in other table I am passing country names:

`country = {"India", "Australia", "India"}`

I want output table like:

`out_table = {Sachin="India", Ponting="Australia", Dhoni="India"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straight-forward attempt:

```
names = {'Sachin', 'Ponting', 'Dhoni'}
countries = {"India", "Australia", "India"}

function table_map(names, countries)
    local out = {}
    for i, each in ipairs(names) do
        out[each] = countries[i]
    end
    return out
end

out_table = table_map(names, countries)
```

[**Live repl demo**](http://repl.it/M1P/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can make a new iterator that get values from both sequences:

```
function both_values(t1, t2)
    local i = 0
    return function() i = i + 1; return t1[i], t2[i] end
end
```

Then use the iterator like this:

```
local out_table = {}
for v1, v2 in both_values(names, country) do
    out_table[v1] = v2
end
```

Comment: It is giving error . stdin:2: attempt to index global `out_table' (a nil value)

Comment: @PrashantGaur Are you testing the program in the Lua interpreter line by line? If so, declare `out_table` as global, i.e, `out_table = {}` without `local`.

Comment: why this  ? can you explain i am new to lua

Comment: @PrashantGaur Because in interactive mode, each line is a chunk by itself (unless it is incomplete). When you entered the next line, the previous local declaration is out of scope.